# Child classes and parent classes in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently watching [Bucky's Python Programming](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=36&number=34) tutorials. He has explained the concept of child classes and parent classes, like so:

```
class Dad:
    var1 = "Hey I'm Dad"

class Mum:
    var2 = "Hey I'm Mum"

class Child(Mum, Dad):
    var3 = "Hey I'm a Child"
```

This, I understand completely. However, he then turns the classes into an object:

```
childObject = Child()

dadObject = Dad()
```

Why would he bother doing this, if he can just call `Child.var3` to get the same result as `childObject.var3`?

Comment: I'd be interested to see a link to this "tutorial"...

Comment: Here: http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=36&number=34

Comment: Okay - please disregard what he's saying - I've managed to watch that (and it's painful), and he doesn't have a clue what he's talking about regarding Python classes and design... So the reason is, the correct way is to not initialise the object if you want to access a class attribute, and that he's very confused about things...

Comment: Okay, thanks. So calling the class `Child.var3` is perfectly valid?

Comment: Yup - but using classes solely for attribute access is just odd...

Comment: ummm sort of... thats a Class Variable instead of an Instance variable ...

Comment: The tutorial is using classes as nothing more than namespaces ... which is not something you generally do in Python, and if that is what you're using them for, instantiating them (`whateverObject = whateverClass()` in the video) is pointless. I'd look for some [better learning materials](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) ...

Comment: There's really only one reason to ever have a class with no instance attributes and no instance methods and make instances of it: to get distinct objects with different `id`s but the same `type`. This is something you will very rarely need to do. The only thing worth learning from this tutorial is that not every tutorial is worth following…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a better example is

```
class Person:
    name="Person"
    def speak(self):
        print "Hi! Im %s"%slf.name

class Dad(Person):
     name = "Dad"

class Mom(Person):
     name = "Mom"

class Child(Person):
     name = "a Child"
     age  = 5
     def speak(self):
        print "Hewwo, I am a %d year old child!"%self.age

d = Dad()
m = Mom()
c = Child()

c.speak()
m.speak()
d.speak()
```

as to the difference (your question of static class access versus instance access)

```
class Child:
   var3 = "whatever"

c = Child()
c.var3 = "something_else"

print c.var3
print Child.var3
```